# Why an unexpected <br> being inserted by replace() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm seeing some very unexpected behavior with the replace() javascript function that I'm using. Essentially, if the user inputs *[Hi there]* into a text form, I want to replace the brackets **[** and **]** with tags that will add margin to the text for e.g. `[Hi there]` to `<div>Hi there</div>`. In addition to the desired tags, a `<br>` tag is also added after the closing div.

Here is my code:

javascript

```
$('.servicebody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(string.replace(/\[/g, '<div class="marginme">')); // to replace opening square bracket
});

$('.servicebody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(string.replace(/\]/g, '</div>')); // to replace closing square bracket
});
```

css

```
.marginme {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Any thoughts on why a `<br>` tag is being inserted by this replace() function?

Comment: `replace()` won't insert arbitrary tags/text, so either you are adding the `<br>` somewhere else, it was already somewhere in the dom, or some other library/code is inserting it. Also note inserting partial html will cause the browser to do syntax error correction (ie close a div or other element)

Comment: Please re-read your question and see if it is really making sense because I personally couldn't understand what you are trying to ask. :(

Comment: Ok, i'll revise it.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. The browser must be doing syntax correction. I can't think of any other explanation.

Comment: Syntax correction won't insert tags that weren't there before, it simply fixes (eg closes) tags. You will need to provide a [mcve] to get a proper diagnosis

Comment: This works fine!

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I've updated my example so that it is simplified. I'll see if I can figure out a code pen.

Comment: Works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/2kfrbp58/

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I'm going to insert my own code in to that jsfiddle to see if I get the same result as what I'm seeing in Chrome. I'll let you know. Thanks so much!

Comment: There is no need for two loops, you can do something like this instead `$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g, "<div....>$1</div>"))` but you should probably find some other solution because it is never a good idea to parse HTML using regex.

Comment: @Patrick. Had a look at jsfiddle. I'm certain the browser is adding the <br /> tag.

Comment: You are treating the dom as if it is a text editor....it's not. Elements can only be inserted as complete elements. You can't insert closing tags later. Also are you doing this on a `contenteditable` element?

Comment: Thanks guys. I've decided to use markdown based on the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you insert the HTML below you close the tags. Try the following code, instead:

```
$('.servicebody').each(function() {
    var string = $(this).html();    
    $(this).html(string.replace(/\[/g , '<div class="bulletflex"><div class="bullet"></div><div class="bullet2">').replace(/\]/g, '</div></div>'));    
});
```

Comment: Sorry. Tried this out and the result is the exact same. Also, you use a [ symbol at the end where there should be a ]. Not a big deal as I caught it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

1. I would recommend you to use one single function instead of two. Using two functions, as you did in your sample code, only makes unnecessarily calculations.
2. As best practice I would reccomend you to store `this` into a variable. Otherwise this could lead to unexpected behavior.
3. Avoid multiple calls of the jquery functions: make `$(lorem).ipsum();$(lorem).xyz()` to `var $lorem = $(lorem);$lorem.ipsum();$lorem.xyz();`

Here is my version of your code:

```
$('.servicebody').each(function() {
    var self = this;
    var $self = $(self);

    var html = $self.html();

    html = html.replace(/\[/g, '<div class="marginme">');
    html = html.replace(/\]/g, '</div>');

    $self.html(html);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The code is cleaner, but it still produces a <br> tag. I'm pretty sure that the browser is doing this. I'm trying to figure out an alternative way to do this.

Comment: It could also be another js library. Which other tools do you use?

Comment: I think that I'll just use markdown. Seems like it will be easier.

Answer (score -1):

i think   you  might  try another  syntax

```html
$('.servicebody').empty().add($('</div></div>'));
```

Comment: This deletes all of the user entered text. Won't work. sorry